# How to add a [WebMethod] file for WebService1.asmx?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, web-services, webmethod

I have a project with server side in C#.
I'm connecting to the SQL Server and want to pass it parameters to a table.

How do I open a WebMethod file ? I can't find it anywhere
neither a WebService project.

[image]

**P.S**
I read that WebService asmx is obsolete, but by using a ASP.NET Core Web API project I will not be able to pass parameters to SQL from the server side in the Chrome browser.

Thanks is advance.

Comment: *ASP.NET Core Web API project I will not be able to pass parameters to SQL* - you think netcore doesn't support parameterized SQL?

Comment: @CaiusJard Everyone is telling me something else. I haven't even manage to open my ASP.NET Core Web API (same code project as the asmx) in the chrome. I'm not working with Entity Framework Core. All I want is help with the WebMethod, later on other question you/I will see about `ASP.NET Core Web API`

Comment: I was working on Asp.net before, I recommend you don't spend time learning it just switch to Asp.net core immediately :)

Comment: @AFarmanbar I already learned WebService , I must send parameters through the chrome to the SQL. ASP.NET Core Web API is new to me and I don't know it's limits and I'm having trouble right now with it, if you can help me with it in Discord I'll be grateful.

Answer (score 1):

I think you might be slightly confused; `[WebMethod]` isn't a type of file, it's an attribute you apply to methods in your service to mark them as available for calling remotely. Once you've added the attribute to a method, it will appear in the list of methods exported in the service's webservice definition

```
using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]

public class Service : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
    public Service ()
    {

    }


    [WebMethod]
    public string GetTime()
    {
        return DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss");
    }

    public string GetDate()
    {
        return DateTime.Today.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
    }
}
```

If you ran this you'd see:

[image]

GetTime, but no GetDate, because GetDate isn't marked as a webmethod

ASMX is very old - it's simple, but very old.. It's increasingly rare to even find people creating XML based webservices (alas) these days, but if they do they probably use WCF, not ASMX

I would recommend you switch to netcore API; the templates work out of the box - you get a Weather Forecast one I think - you can just create a new project, hit play and it works. You can interact with it using e.g. Postman or Insomnia. You can add new operations, it does support parameterized queries to SQL, you don't need EF.. And it'll be  JSON based, which is pretty much the direction the modern web has gone in

Comment: I had troubles what does `How do I open a WebMethod file ?` mean. either way.

Comment: So I just need to add to my ShopWebApplication1 project a cs file with such coded ? As you can see above I have WebService1.asmx file, how do I connect between those two ?

Comment: I tried to find WCF in visual studio 2019 projects but couldn't find. As for net core WEB API I tried to open it in chrome but field and I was told that even with Postman I will not be able to send parameters to SQL Server. I must be precise with what I'm doing and not jumping from one  method to the other.

Comment: You don't "connect the two", you write the webmethods in the code file associated with the asmx. Double click the AMSX or right click it and choose code view. WCF is old too. I'm not really sure how you can fail to open it; you just make a new Web API project and press play.. But it's important to note that it won't do anything obvious in the browser; web services aren't intended for browsers to consume - theyre websites that *scripts* use, not humans

Comment: If you're talking about using an existing ASMX WebService1 from another project, right click the References node and choose add service/web reference, and put the URL in to the asmx

Comment: @CaiusJard did you check it really ? https://im.ge/i/LmeOp here are the webmethods in WebService. and No I opened a new project from scratch.

Comment: But are you trying to make that new project use an existing webservice, or are you trying to create a webservice?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235513/discussion-between-elassoa-and-caius-jard). I'm in the chat..

Comment: @CaiusJard your code above doesn't help me, I know how to write WebMethod code, its the file I need, I'm in the chat above

Comment: You aren't making much sense. Tell me what is inside this file/what would I see when I open it in a text editor?

Comment: @CaiusJard Can I chat with you some how ? this is getting too long this way.

Comment: I have a life outside SO I'm afraid; chat is not convenient for me

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by opening a new project as: **ASP.NET Empty Web Site**. 
I added it a new item as "Web Service (ASMX)" which created a `WebService.asmx` file and also a `WebService.cs` file inside a `App_Code` folder.

The `ASP.NET Web Application` I opened before in this question had build in a `WebMethod` inside ASMX file I added, 
  as I shown here -

**WebService1.asmx**

```
Public Class WebService1
Inherits System.Web.Services.WebService

<WebMethod()> _
Public Function HelloWorld() As String
    Return "Hello World"
End Function

End Class
```

Which I'm not familiar with this convention of how to implement webMethods in it.
If you know how to write `<WebMethod()> _` this way I'll be grateful for your answer :)

**Thanks**

Comment: That's VB. You tagged your question [c#]